# Tcl: Join list of strings with the string from another variable?

Tags: string, tcl

How it is possible to join the string from a variable with a list of strings?
More exactly, I have this:

```
set Dir "02_E12_SP_el";
set OutputDir [join {$Dir _ forcesElem21.out} ""];
```

I want `OutputDir` to be `"02_E12_SP_el_forcesElem21.out"`, but instead I obtain `"$Dir_forcesElem21.out"`

Comment: It sounds like you're working with filenames. If you are and you're trying to insert directory name separators, use `file join` which is aware of a number of subtleties that aren't immediately obvious.

Answer (score 2):

When you wrap a variable in braces {}, it will not be interpreted
as a variable.

```
{$Dir _ forcesElem21.out}
```

creates a static list.

There are several methods.

The join command concatenates a list of elements together.
It is more useful when the list is already built and has
the flexibility to specify what to join with (e.g. {, }).

```
set var 123
set mystr abc
set newstr [join [list $mystr def $var] {}]
```

Direct concatentation:

```
set var 123
set mystr abc$var
set mystr ${var}abc
```

Or the append command:

```
set var 123
set mystr abc
append mystr $var
```

References: [append](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/append.htm), [join](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/join.htm)

Comment: @miculas13, the direct concatenation seems the simplest option: `set OutputDir ${Dir}_forcesElem21.out`

Comment: @miculas13: from Tcl 8.6.2 you can also use `string cat $Dir _ forcesElem21.out` to get the value you wanted. If your list of elements is itself in a variable, use `string cat {*}$elements`. See https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/string.htm#M5.